# LVS router stopped working after reboot

Tags: load-balancing, rhel6, lvs, piranha

I am using RHEL 6.8 for load balancing using LVS direct routing. For some reason I had to restart my LVS router.
after rebooting, LVS service was not working

I have done following things, still it is not working

```
/sbin/chkconfig --level 0123456 iptables on
/sbin/chkconfig --level 0123456 piranha-gui on
/sbin/chkconfig --level 0123456 pulse on
/sbin/chkconfig --level 0123456 sshd on
service httpd restart
service piranha-gui restart
service pulse restart
ipvsadm -A -t 10.209.104.60:80 -s rr
ipvsadm -a -t 10.209.104.60:80 -r 10.209.104.7:80 -g
ipvsadm -a -t 10.209.104.60:80 -r 10.209.104.5:80 -g
```

ifconfig command is **not showing**  VIP as a alias to eth0 (which I think, should be automatically configured from /etc/sysconfig/ha/lvs.cf file)

LOG file entries

> lvsprimary pulse[3143]: STARTING PULSE AS MASTER
>
> lvsprimary pulse[3143]: partner dead: activating lvs
>
> lvsprimary lvsd[3147]: starting virtual service loadbalancer active:80
>
> lvsprimary kernel: IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
>
> lvsprimary kernel:IPVS: __ip_vs_del_service: enter
>
> lvsprimary lvsd[3147]: create_monitor for loadbalancer/server1 running as pid 3151
>
> lvsprimary lvsd[3147]: create_monitor for loadbalancer/server2 running as pid 3152
>
> lvsprimary nanny[3152]: starting LVS client monitor for 10.###.###.##:80 -> 10.2##.###.7:0
>
> lvsprimary nanny[3151]: starting LVS client monitor for 10.###.###.##:80 -> 10.2##.###.5:0
>
> lvsprimary pulse[3154]: gratuitous lvs arps finished

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ?

Comment: @istheEnglishway not as such. when I run **service pulse restart**, the log messages ended with the message **gratuitous lvs arps finished** (which means the settings are normal) however, when I i used wireshark to trace the packets flow, I found that lvs router, it self is replying, unlike forwarding request to real servers as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the logs file, all the services are configured normally.
As I mentioned in the one of the comments that, all configurations are normal but the problem is with packet forwading, even though ipvsadm rules are correcly stated.

> PROBLEM

firewall rules are configured to default at the time of bootup

> SOLUTION

run following command to flush all firewall rules

```
iptables -F
```

we can achieve this at bootup itself, just add this commands in the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`